# JQuery ajax FormData: file not added to POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, file-upload

Trying to upload a file, `var_dump($_POST)` from the code below shows that ajax is not setting up `$_POST['file']`. I have no error message other than that so I don't know where Im going wrong.

VAR DUMP RESULT

```
array(1) {
["action"]=>
string(20) "uploadNewUserPicture"
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="userInfoUploadProfilePic">   
  <form id="userUploadProfilePicForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="userInfoFormTitle">UPLOAD PROFILE PICTURE</div>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="userImg"></input>
  <br>
  <input id="submitPictureButton" type="button" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
</div
```

JS

```
var file = $('#userImg')[0].files[0];
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('action', 'uploadNewUserPicture');
formData.append('file', file );

$.ajax({
     url: "php/upload.php",
     type: "post",
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     data: formData,
     success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
     },
    error: handleAjaxError,
   });
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
  var_dump($_POST);
  $action = $_POST['action'];
  $var = $_POST['file'];

  switch($action) {
   case 'uploadNewUserPicture' : uploadNewUserPicture($var);break;
  }
};
```

Comment: did you check `$_FILES['file']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload files, you need to use [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

> $_FILES An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. The structure of this array is outlined in the POST method uploads section.

```
$fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']; 
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
```

and to upload a file, in your PHP you need the `tmp_name` and the `name` of the file. Your `uploadNewUserPicture($var)` function should be have the following  parameter signature

```
uploadNewUserPicture($tmp_name, $image_name);
```

Comment: ACE !! Thank you